# Create a class object from another class in python

Tags: python, class, object, pyqt

I am new in python, and I am trying to create an object in one class, and then  delete that same object from another class.

This is part of the code:

```
class Win(QMainWindow):
 list_1 = []              #This lists are filled with objects
 list_2 = []
 def __init__(self):
   #A lot of stuff in here

   self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)

 def addObject(self):
   plot = Matplotlib()     #This is another class where i create a matplotlib figure   
   if len(Win.list_1) < 2:
     self.splitter.addWidget(plot)
```

So, with this, i create an object if the number of items in list_1 is lower than 3, and then i add it to list_1 and list_2, and i add it to the splitter of course. This works fine. Now, i create a method to delete this splitter (with the object inside of it too) like this:

```
  deleteObject(self):
    if len(Win.list_1) == 1:
      widget_erased = self.splitter.widget(index)
      widget_erased.hide()
      widget_erased.deleteLater()
```

As you can see, if i have 1 object, i can delete it. The problem comes when i have more objects. In this same method i write:

```
    if len(Win.list_1) > 1:
    #I open A QDialog where i see the names of the objects from the lists in a QListWidget
      self.delete = Delete()      
      self.delete.exec_()
```

Now, this is the class with the QDialog:

```
class Delete(self):
  def _init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def deleteObjectCreated(self):
    #There are another things before the next lines

    widget_erased = Win.splitter.widget(index)   
    widget_erased.hide()
    widget_erased.deleteLater()
```

with this last method, i select the object in the QDialog, and when i press a button, the object is deleted from both lists, but the splitter remains, and i get this error:

`type object "Win" has no attribute "splitter"`

How can i accomplish this? I mean, delete the object that i choose from the QDialog, that is created in another class?

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `splitter` via the **class** object rather than the **instance** object.

In your example, this can be solved by setting the instance object (i.e. `self`) as the parent of the `Delete` dialog:

```
class Win(QMainWindow):
    ...

    def deleteObject(self):
        ...
        if len(self.list_1) > 1:
            self.delete = Delete(self) # set self as the parent


class Delete(self):
    def _init__(self, parent):
        super(Delete, self).__init__(parent)
        ...

    def deleteObjectCreated(self):
        widget_erased = self.parent().splitter.widget(index)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

'Win' is class object and this object is not having 'splitter' attribute. If I refer **init** of class 'Win' it looks like splitter is attribute of instance of 'Win' not the attribute of class 'Win'

```
self.splitter.QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
```

So you rightly getting error when you try to access Win.splitter.

This should be part of your design that splitter should be instance attribute or class attribute, I am not suggesting any thing on your design. But just to work your code If you want to access Win.splitter then do below change :-

```
def __init__(self):
   #A lot of stuff in here

   Win.splitter.QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
```

or You can change def deleteObjectCreated(self) as below:-

```
def deleteObjectCreated(self, instance_win):
    instance_win.splitter.QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can not make that change, because i will have errors from another methods that i have made. Is there another way to make it work?

Comment: Then can you pass instance of Win to def deleteObjectCreated(self, instance_win), then access instance_win.splitter ?